# Why doesn't razor detect this as a code block in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following snippet:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <li>@product.Name x@product.Count</li>
}
</ul>
```

It treats x@product.Count as a literal.  How can I have a character placed right before the @ symbol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That scenario is there to allow `foo@your.com` (emails) to exist unmolested in existing markup. Instead, use:

```
x@(product.Count)
```

(the extra brackets immediately after `@`, i.e. `@(...)` indicate an explicit code expression)

or better html-wise:

```
&times;@(product.Count)
```

You might also then find this works conveniently:

```
&times;@product.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>@product.Name x@(product.Count)</li>
```